# open weather map API not providing right data with python requests

Tags: python, speech-recognition, openweathermap

So, i am making a voice assistant using speech recognition in python. I am using Open Weather Map API. The API is returning wrong results when called in my python program.

The API perfectly works and returns right results when i use the link with a given api key on the web but when i use it in my python program it returns wrong results with some cities like Mumbai, Dehli, Kolkata but right results when i ask it the New York weather. It is wierd!!

query is the statement commanded by me like - "What is the weather in New York"

```
elif "weather" in query:

            query = query.strip(" weather in ")
            query = query.replace(" ", "")

            url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=xxxxx&units=metric'.format(query)
            res = requests.get(url)
            data = res.json()

            temp = data['main']['temp']
            wind_speed = data['wind']['speed']
            description = data['weather'][0]['description']
            print(str(description) + " with a temperature of " + str(temp) + "°C and a wind speed of " + str(wind_speed) + " km/hr")
            speak(str(description) + " with a temperature of " + str(temp) + "°C and a wind speed of " + str(wind_speed) + " kilometer per hour")
```

Comment: Maybe its better to provide the country code in addition to the city, try that way

Comment: @amrs-tech can you give an example

Comment: Actually if you look into openweather API docs, there will be an example, just an addition of parameter in the fetch URL, maybe refer this, it could help : https://openweathermap.org/current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `strip` does not work like that. Strip literally removes any prefix and suffix consisting of those characters. It does NOT cut or remove the given part.

In your case:

```
>>> print("what is the weather in new york".strip(" weather in "))
s the weather in new york
```

Another examples:

```
>>> print("aaaaaaaaabsomethinghereaa".strip("a"))
bsomethinghere
>>> print("aaaaaaaaabsomethinghereaa".strip("ab"))
somethinghere
>>> print("1234567aabsomethinghereaa".strip("ab7654321"))
somethinghere
```

As you can see, the order doesn't matter, any combination of those characters gets removed from beginning and end.

---

That gives us second step: debugging.

If something doesn't work as intended, check whether you call it right. If you work with text like here, print each step of the text manipulation. You only compared your script results with manual results, without checking each step that led to those results.

---

How to fix this part?

You have to cut your string and leave only city in there. This means you have to find the ending of the "weather in" and just take everything beyond that.

For finding beginning of the substring you can use `find`. If you want an end, add the length of the text.

```
>>> query = "what is the weather in new york"
>>> query = query[query.find("weather in")+10:]
>>> query = query.replace(" ", "")
>>> print(query)
newyork
```

Comment: Well you solved my problem in the description and temperature part though it is 1 degree off but i can work with it but the wind speed is off like for kolkata it the wind speed is 2 km/hr where as google shows the wind speed as 11km/hr

Comment: Please look again at second step. It's possible that it doesn't recognise when you say Kolkata and gives you some strange name instead.

Comment: So debugged it and it accepted the city name = "Kolkata" which is right

Comment: So it turned i did not realize that the unit of wind speed was in m/s i thought it was in km/hr.